# Image invalid sent by ANDROID to C# TCPListener

Tags: android, image, sockets, tcplistener

I'm send image from android to a TCPClient in C# but when receive image, this is invalid image.

I have created a method to validate stream but no have image header.

Anyone can help me?

**Here my ANDROID code:**
    try {

```
        Socket sockTcp = new Socket(EnderecoSoftclinic, PORTATCP);

        while(sockTcp.isClosed()){

            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Tentando conectar ao SoftClinic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            sockTcp.connect(sockTcp.getRemoteSocketAddress(), PORTATCP);

        }

        OutputStream outputStream = sockTcp.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(imagem,0,imagem.length);

        outputStream.flush();

        sockTcp.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**And my receive C# Code:**

```
        TcpListener tcpReceiver = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2553);

        tcpReceiver.Start(1);

        while (!finalizado)
        {
            TcpClient android = tcpReceiver.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream stream = android.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = null;

            buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(tamanho)];

            if (stream.CanRead)
            {
               while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0) {}
            }

            if (buffer == null || buffer.Length == 0)
            { return; }

            MemoryStream streamImg = new MemoryStream();
            streamImg.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (!IsValidImage(streamImg))
            {
                finalizado = true;
                return;
            }

            if (File.Exists("C:/teste.bmp"))
            {
                File.Delete("C:/teste.bmp");
            }

            FileStream streamWriter = new FileStream("C:/teste.bmp", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
            streamWriter.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
            try
            {
                Image imagemGerada = Image.FromStream(streamImg);
                if (AoRetornarDadosEquipamento != null)
                {
                    AoRetornarDadosEquipamento(imagemGerada);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }

            stream.Close();
            android.Close();
            finalizado = true;
        }

        tcpReceiver.Stop();
```

Comment: In the line "outputStream.write(imagem,0,imagem.length);"  what type the "imagem" has ?  Is it an Image or Bitmap or byte array ?  The first guess should be this: you are sending not the actual bytes of the image in .bmp format, but just the image contents or even worse - the representation of the Image object.

Comment: is byte[] data...... readed with function:  
public static byte[] lerArquivo (File file) throws IOException {
  
  int size = (int) file.length();
     byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
     
  BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        buf.close();
  return bytes;        
    }

Comment: OK. Then you're reading it correctly (at least if the source file itself is good). Check the number of bytes you receive from the NetworkStream in C#. If the number of bytes is not the same as the number of bytes you've sent in Android, then it is something with TCP transport. If the number of bytes is the same, then it can be the issue with 'signed'/'unsigned' conversion (you will have to compare the files byte by byte if the sizes are the same)

Comment: thanks for your reply victor, but the length is the same,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.. 
In more easily way i just get the NetworkStream in my c# program and CopyTo new Stream.

And done.

Thanks...........

Just need this

```
        NetworkStream stream = android.GetStream();
        MemoryStream streamImg = new MemoryStream();
        stream.copyto(streamimg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem.

The MemoryStream (streamImg) is read once while you save it to the file.

Then you *do not* rewind it and try to load the Image (hence reading past the end of file!). Use

```
 streamImg.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

after the line

```
 streamWriter.Close();
```

This can do the job.

The other way is to recreate the streamImg (this will do practically the same).